# Handling has_one nested resource in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I got a User model and a About model. The about model is a page where users have more info about them that due its nature is more appropriate to have it on a separate model rather than in the user model.

I want to be able to route it to something like /:username/about and get all the verbs working on that path (GET POST, PUT, DELETE).

```
/:username/about
/:username/about/edit
/:username/about
```

This is what I already have

```
# routes.rb
resources :users do 
  resources :abouts
end

match ':username/about' => 'abouts#show', :as => :user_about
match ':username/about/add' => 'abouts#new', :as => :user_new_about    
match ':username/about/edit' => 'abouts#edit', :as => :user_edit_about
```

And in the models I have

```
# about.rb
belongs_to :user

# user.rb
has_one :about
```

When I'm doing a post or put to /roses/about It's interpreting It as a show

```
Started POST "/roses/about" for 127.0.0.1 at Sun Feb 27 16:24:18 -0200 2011
  Processing by AboutsController#show as HTML
```

I'm probably missing the declaration in the routes, but doesn't it get messy declaring each verb for a resource when it's different from the default?

What's the simplest and cleaner way to archive this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `scope` and `controller` blocks to cut down on the verbiage:

```
  scope "/:username" do
    controller :abouts do
      get 'about' => :show
      post 'about' => :create
      get 'about/add' => :new
      get 'about/edit' => :edit
    end
  end
```

which produces:

```
     about GET /:username/about(.:format) {:action=>"show", :controller=>"abouts"}
           POST /:username/about(.:format) {:action=>"create", :controller=>"abouts"}
 about_add GET /:username/about/add(.:format) {:controller=>"abouts", :action=>"new"}
about_edit GET /:username/about/edit(.:format) {:controller=>"abouts", :action=>"edit"}
```

Comment: That's what I been looking for!

Answer (score 11):

When using a `has_one`, it might make sense to declare it as a singular resource in your routes. Meaning

```
resources :users do
  resource :about # notice "resource" and not "resources"
end
```

And if you want to override the paths for new/edit, add a `:path_names` option to the resource/resources-call:

`resources :about, :path_names => { :new => 'add', :edit => 'edit' }`

The [official documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) has lots of other tips and tricks for routing as well.

Comment: This is what I have been looking for

Comment: This answer is more rails-ish.