# Getting an error when trying to associate a menu to a restaurant rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been struggling the past few days trying to get a basic restaurant website up. The website will be listing a bunch of restaurants and each of them will have a menu.

My menu association

```
class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :store
end

class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :menu
end
```

My routes for now is:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  resources :stores do
    resources :menus

  end

root 'stores#index'
```

I did the migration for adding references to stores. The problem occurs when I try to create a link_to button for adding a new menu in the restaurant show page.

```
<%= link_to 'Create menu', new_store_menu_path %>
```

This gives me the error when I try to load the show.html.erb

```
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"menus", :id=>"1"} missing required keys: [:store_id]
```

Thanks all!

Comment: can you post your menu controller?

Comment: Did my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

you need a column `store_id` in your table `menu`

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Comment: Already have one, if i add another it gives me an error saying there's a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need add controller and action
app/controller/menus_controller.rb

```
class MenusController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_menu, only: [:new]
def new

end
private
  def set_menu
    @menu = Menu.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For a `has_one` association,you need to use single `resource`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  resources :stores do
    resource :menu     #note the changes resource and menu

  end

root 'stores#index'
```

**[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135113/handling-has-one-nested-resource-in-rails-3)**

And also as the error suggest that `store_id` is missing.Make sure you have it in the `menus` table

Comment: Tried changing the resources, same thing. I thought the references thing from the migration adds the store_id correct?

Comment: @user3617865 Yes it adds.